# Single point grounding VS Uniform ground plane

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, signal-integrity

Intro:

I think I have read/seen too many articles pointing out why having a single uniform ground plane is the superior grounding strategy in comparision to split ground planes or irregular ground planes, and they say single point grounding is probably the worst having worst EMI signatures. I think I understand their logic and agree on most part.

Except one tiny little detail that no one streches on and is bugging me for quite a while now.

Question:

To make things simpler let's assume displacment currents dont exist. I know this is a pretty stupid assumption. But I don't know how else to make this not sound too much complicated.

Scenario 1):Consider a PCB like this:
[image]

Bottom plane is ground plane. So wouldn't this force return paths of all the IC's to be common and cause Signal Integrity Problems. Consider IC is A is doing a lot of switching and causing ground to bounce and generating noise on its ground pin. Now since B ,and C will share the same return path their gound pins will pick up A's ground noise. And similarly if B where doing a lot of switching too, C would see a even more disturbed ground

Scenario 2):Consider a PCB like this:
[image]

There is no ground place and we use single point grounding. My brain predicts this PCB layout should be better help isolate ground noise of all IC's.

So what am I missing? why do all PCB designer veterans use unifrom ground?

Comment: If you can use a 4-plane PCB (one for ground, one for Vcc) would be "better" because, with the decoupling capacitor, noise is probably "minimized). But in the older time, tens of digital circuits were using option Vcc (with only 1 plane) in the first picture as well for ground ... with decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of solutions to make things better, but I am not looking for solutions I am looking for just the comparision. I am just questioning the fundamentals for better understanding them.

Comment: Check the ground path resistance to the power ground connection for each part.

Comment: Ask yourself is a wire really a perfect conductor? Is anything? Stick an inductor and resistor in the middle of every trace on your PCB.

Answer (score 5):

> I think I have read/seen too many articles pointing out why having a single uniform ground plane is the superior grounding strategy in comparison to split ground planes or irregular ground planes, and they say single point grounding is probably the worst having worst EMI signatures.

That's the case if the circuits are fast enough for the star-connected traces to be of a length similar to the wavelength of working frequencies - especially edges. This would be the case for digital circuits, and the traditional perpendicular routing of TTL designs on 2-layer boards was a bit of a horror show in that respect.

In analog circuits working at much lower frequencies than TTL edge harmonics, single point grounds may be the way to go if a ground plane is not available. Have a look at older power supply PCB artwork that predates CAD: lots of single-point grounding on 2-layer designs is used to obtain good DC and low-frequency performance. Same goes for audio amps.

To convert those designs to a 2-layer board with one layer being groundplane would require the groundplane to be either split strategically to mimic single-point grounding, or use the groundplane only for low-current control circuitry, and star connections for high current stuff.

If you are designing a modern high-current circuit such as an amplifier or a power supply, a ground plane won't save you - especially since modern designs are usually higher current than older ones. E.g. a 600mA 20V linear bench supply was a viable product 40 years ago. Today, the same case size can easily fit a 1.5A 40V design, without even trying hard. But higher currents imply larger drops along the ground plane, so routing high-current circuits still requires care and usually they need to be separated from the low-current ground plane.

Comment: Suppose I was designing a high speed PCB, wouldn't the high current problem you described affect similarly in high speed ciruits? the ground reference for each component needs to be a flat line. If there is there is so much switching it will impart noise on the entire ground plane. Which should be even worse. So why use ground planes?

Comment: @AbhimanyuSIngh " it will impart noise on the entire ground plane" -- that is your assertion, not ours! This is a statement which requires proof to justify it. I think you will find an illuminating answer in that direction.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSIngh Noise voltage is produced by currents flowing through impedances. Make the impedances low and the noise voltage will be low. That’s what the ground plane provides: a low impedance circuit between the reference nodes. Then driving pulse currents through it won’t generate much noise voltage. So, the thicker the copper and the closer the reference nodes are placed on the ground plane, the better it gets. That’s also how modern designs leverage small component sizes: they inherently  reduce noise by just keeping things nearby.

Comment: So would you say, for mordern day PCB designs and components a uniform ground plane will be always the better solution? and you see no scenario or circumstances that a different gorunding strategy to be better?

Answer (score 4):

As you stipulate no GND plane in the 2nd case, and also do not indicate bypass capacitors, the current loops look like so:

[image: Current loops on star connection]

There is considerable mutual flux between these loops; even if the areas aren't shared (by different arrangement, or even non-planar construction), they are chained along V<sub>CC</sub>, whose trace inductance will share some ripple between them.  If we star V<sub>CC</sub> as well, we still have the self-inductance of the links between device and star node(s), plus whatever shared impedance is presented at the V<sub>CC</sub>/GND connection points.  (Obviously, the latter is mostly solved by introducing adequate bypass there.)

I'm not sure what else to do, given the assumption that displacement currents don't exist; should magnetic induction be ignored as well?  That would be symmetrical, but perhaps not intended, and obviously defeats the above observations.

On the other hand, ignoring electric field effects can be reasonable, when the circuit impedance is much less than \$Z_0\$, and frequencies are much less than resonant frequencies of the structures (i.e., we can ignore transmission line or wave effects).  Which is typically the case for on-board PDN (power distribution network) analyses; this might be more the intended case?  If so, then this paragraph explains what important properties distinguish that operating condition, and how to better describe it.  (For short, I'd go with something like: "low-Z, low-F approximation".)

As for the typical reason to choose star connections -- this is largely a DC thing, as the voltage drop to each unit A/B/C is predominantly its own (current draw times trace resistance), so isolation is obtained in the DC case (i.e., the voltage offset at A does not depend on the current flows at B/C/etc.).  Clearly this is not the case, for the given arrangement, at AC, and this is where many run into huge trouble when trying to apply star connections in practice.

Finally, note that the picture becomes even more complicated when we include interconnections between local subcircuits.  If A drives a signal into B, then there is a signal current between V<sub>CC</sub>/GND and those connection(s), splitting the loops further, and introducing more opportunity for AC errors.  If we have connections between A and C, they must cross over, or around, the A and B loops, incurring still more coupling that is hard to predict.

---

Whereas, in the first (ground plane) case, the supply currents can return through the V<sub>CC</sub> trace (and underneath and near it, driven as you will by displacement currents or magnetic induction), and we can have signals routed around (say, down and then inbetween) subcircuits A/B/C/etc. and have good isolation, while still tracking with respect to the local ground plane reference voltage.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to show star VCC connection in the second scenario.

Comment: Yes this thought experiment is for low-F approximation and DC currents. BUT the noise imparted onto the ground connection is can be high frequencies.

Comment: Your point about interconnections is valid, but this question is for the scenario where no intereconnections are there. What I basically wanted to show was there are different circuit blocks on PCB. Each circuit block has many IC's who have interconnections to each other and each cicuit block has an isolated ground plane shaped to the borders of the ciruit block underneath. Now these circuit blocks are tied with single point grounding. So each circuit blocks ground plane is connected to the ground source pin through a isolated track.

Comment: So do you agree single point grounding is a better strategy for DC power distribution?

Comment: If you agree, Now lets ask the real question. Consider there are High speed signals tracks well in the 10Mhz range on a PCB. 

Scenario 1.)High speed signals tracks routed over a uniform ground plane. Here it will cause ground bounce, all signals disturbing each other

Scenario 2.)High speed signals tracks each routed with a ground track just alongside it just like a differential pair. Here all signals seem isolated and don't affect each other. All the displacment current exist between the sig-gnd tracks only, helping in SI and also lower EMI.

What do you say?

Comment: I agree; but DC is the trivial case! I could run wires like spaghetti through the air, group them any way I like.  Indeed, using a PCB for DC distribution in this way seems rather unnecessary, inconvenient even!

Comment: @AbhimanyuSIngh What are the circumstances of this "real" question? (And if it's ""real"", why not ask that in the OP?...!!) Is this in the same circumstance, so the traces in question are within individual ground-plane blocks? To whom do you presume it will cause ground bounce? (Within the same block? Between blocks? Radiated to space?) What spacing, between traces or components within the block, has been used?  Finally, for the differential case, how pray tell shall you resolve the differences between apparent "ground" signals? They *are* signals now! You can't simply tie them to plane!

Comment: I think you are right this is getting too deep and complicated maybe I should create a more specific new thread for such a question explaining all the circumstances and details.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 2 has the big drawback that the long trace must be considered as an inductor, especially if IC A switches high currents. So there will be a lot of radiated noise, that other traces may receive. This can be even worse than the scenario 1.
You can mitigate this with local capacitors close to IC A, but this will help as well in scenario 1.
There are exceptions where scenario 2 has advantages, e.g. if IC A consumes large DC currents and the ground current below IC B and C would affect analog measurements processed there.